# Continuity on compact set

Tags: continuity, uniform-continuity

If $f:[0,2]\to\Bbb R$ be defined by $f(x)=\frac {1}{x^2 -2}$. Is f uniformly continuous.

- I know continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous. But here it is not so. Because as $n \to \sqrt2 ,   the function f(x)$ goes to $\infty$.
- where does my concept goes wrong  ?

Comment: The key is that every continuous functions is uniformly continuous. But not every function is continuous. In this case, your function is not continuous.

Comment: Your function is not really defined on $[0,2]$ because it is not defined at $\sqrt{2}$. So its domain is $[0,\sqrt{2})\cup (\sqrt{2},2]$, which is not closed and bounded.

Comment: Yes, even if you define $f(\sqrt{2}) = k$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$. It would not be continuous on $[0, 2]$, so you cannot apply the uniform continuity theorem.

Comment: .But in the book counterexamples in analysis by Bernard R. Gelbaum & John M.H. Olmsted this example is given to not to be uniformly continuous function which is continuous on a closed and bdd interval

Comment: @AlexanderAgüero As you wrote that first phrase in your comment it is false. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I think its typing mistake

Comment: @gobindachandra Where **exactly** in Gelbaum's book appears that example? Because there can't possibly be a continuous function in a closed and bounded interval (i.e., a compact subset) that is *not* uniformly continuous...

Comment: The Real Number System, page 19. Example (a)

Comment: There also given a function which is sai to be continuous and bdd on a closed interval but not uniformly continuous.

Comment: @gobindachandra Thank you, found it. That is a colossal mistake in that book, as simply as that.

Comment: Is the second counterexample true? I this that is also not continuous on \sqrt2

Comment: @gobindachandra Nop, also that one is heavily mistaken. In both cases one can find counterexamples in closed *unbounded* intervals, but the examples given there are in bounded closed intervals...very strange. These are very elementary, basic and even easy to prove properties of continuous functions. Perhaps that book has a different set of axioms....very, very odd. The first example, the one in your question, is even worse: the function isn't even well defined in the given interval.

Comment: @DonAntonio, I mean, every continuous functions defined on a compact is uniformly continuous, bus in this case the function isn't continuous, so we can talk about uniformly continuous

Comment: @AlexanderAgüero I thought you did mean something like that.\

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined at
$$D=[0,\sqrt {2}[\cup ]\sqrt {2},2] $$

take
$$x_n=\sqrt {2}+\frac {1}{n}$$
$x_n\in D $ and $(x_n) $ is Cauchy.

but

$f (x_n)=\frac {n^2   }{  1+2n\sqrt {2}}$

is not Cauchy cause it diverges.
So $f $ is not uniformly continuous at $D $.

Comment: This was already addressed in one of the comments. The gist is that the quoted book gives the example as the question writes it, and it is wrong.

Comment: @Sa I know that. This was addressed in the second comment, by kccu

Comment: the domain is not closed as you defined .

Comment: @DonAntonio sorry,  he didn't use Cauchy sequences.